# ElasticSearch Query with Punctuations

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I am using Custom Analyzer for the mapping. The input search term is,

message: Overall, It as a good year for this product. Final version released by this year end.

Search Query Term: 'message': 'Overall' or 'product'

I am not getting any results. How to get results when i search without punctuation's and if i search for 'product.' then that should only return exact matched terms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

With your requirements , the query should be like this:

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "overall"
          }
        },
        {
            "match": {
                "message": "\"product\""
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note: This query will return docs that matches `overall` OR `"product"` , depending on how you have `message` analysed this could be exact search or not.

In other hand you must check your document mapping for ensure what analyser are you using in each field if you need exact matches you can work with [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) type and search by [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) .